# Magento2 i recieve HTTP ERROR 500 after backup

Tags: magento2, backup

I did a complete backup with magento2 backup tool and now my website is down and it wont start anymore. Any tips on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

EDIT: Now i get this errors
 [error showed when i acces website](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1zvj)

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---e28_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---e28_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 663, Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(663): file_put_contents('/var/www/vhosts...', 'e28_BLOCK_4F553...', 10)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(179): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->_updateIdsTags(Array, Array, 'merge')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Core.php(390): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'e28_BLOCK_4F553...', Array, 3600)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Core.php(74): Zend_Cache_Core->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'e28_BLOCK_4F553...', Array, 3600, 8)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(47): Magento\Framework\Cache\Core->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'BLOCK_4F55304E8...', Array, 3600)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapter\Zend->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'BLOCK_4f55304e8...', Array, 3600)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php(51): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'BLOCK_4f55304e8...', Array, 3600)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'BLOCK_4f55304e8...', Array, 3600)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache.php(73): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'BLOCK_4f55304e8...', Array, 3600)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Proxy.php(81): Magento\Framework\App\Cache->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'BLOCK_4f55304e8...', Array, 3600)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1123): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Proxy->save('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...', 'BLOCK_4f55304e8...', Array, 3600)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_saveCache('\n\n<!--COLLAPSE-...')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('nav.mobile')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('nav.mobile')
#16 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('nav.mobile')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('navigation.mobi...')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('navigation.mobi...')
#19 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('navigation.mobi...', true)
#20 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Sm/lovefashion/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header-style/header-3.phtml(20): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('navigation.mobi...')
#21 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Sm/lovefashion/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml(17): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#23 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#24 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('header.content')
#28 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header.content')
#29 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header.content')
#30 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#31 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#32 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#34 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#35 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#36 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#37 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#38 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#39 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#40 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#41 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#42 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#43 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#44 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#45 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#46 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#47 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#48 /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#49 {main}
```

Comment: check the excpetion.log in var folder and added in questions.

Comment: increase your memory limit and check the file permissions as recommended for magento2

Comment: @RamaChandranM this is the exception.log for today https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1zvi. The document was located in /var/log/exception.log.
Ruhani, how do i increase memory limit?

Comment: Give permission to `var` folder.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh still not working

Comment: Please check `group/owner` of the file.